# JavaScript - addEventListener "click" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, dom, addeventlistener

I want take a value from input after click on button but all the time function

```js
var buttonToBinary = document.querySelector("#toBinary");
buttonToBinary.addEventListener('click', console.log(getInput()));

function getInput() {
  return document.querySelector("#inputSector").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="userInput" id="inputSector" value="aa" />
<button id="toBinary" type="submit">to binary</button>
```

`getInput()` was started on load page. Please, help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do:

```
buttonToBinary.addEventListener('click', console.log(getInput()));
```

You are passing the returned value of `console.log(...)` to `addEventListener`. That value is `undefined`.

What you want, instead is to wrap that into a function:

```js
var buttonToBinary = document.querySelector("#toBinary");
buttonToBinary.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(getInput())
});

function getInput() {
  return document.querySelector("#inputSector").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="userInput" id="inputSector" value="aa" />
<button id="toBinary" type="submit">to binary</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var buttonToBinary = document.querySelector("#toBinary");

function getInput() {
    return document.querySelector("#inputSector").value;
}

buttonToBinary.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(getInput());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not implement click on button in html? Like this:

```js
function getInput() {
console.log(document.querySelector("#inputSector").value);  
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" name="userInput" id="inputSector" value="aa" />
    <button onclick="getInput()" id="toBinary" type="submit">to binary</button>
  </body>

</html>
```